# Label с HyperLink

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть `QLabel`, его размер `400x400` и в тексте прописано:

```
<a href='-'>Link</a>
```

Мне нужно, чтобы тег `a` растянулся на весь `QLabel` или был такого же размера как `QLabel`.

`width` и `height` не работает!

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: под тэгом что подразумевается?

Comment: @magrif вот это <a href='-'>Link</a>

Comment: растянулся - имеется в виду при клацанье вне `Link`, но в пределах `QLabel`, переходило по сцылке?

Comment: @magrif Да именно это

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужен класс, наследник `QObject`, в котором необходимо переопределить виртуальную функцию `eventFilter(QObject*, QEvent*)`. Допустим, что лэйбл `label` располагается на форме `ui` класса `MainWindow`. В нём же переопределим вышеобозначенную функцию:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    if(watched->objectName() == "label") {
        switch (event->type()) {
        case QEvent::Enter:
            qApp->setOverrideCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);
            break;
        case QEvent::Leave:
            qApp->setOverrideCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
            break;
        case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease:
        case QEvent::MouseButtonPress: {
            QMouseEvent* mevent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
            QLabel* label = static_cast<QLabel*>(watched);
            QFontMetrics metrics( label->font() );
            QTextDocument document;
            document.setHtml(label->text());
            const auto rect = label->rect();
            const auto text = document.toPlainText();

            const auto w = metrics.width(text);
            const auto h = metrics.height();
            const auto align = label->alignment();
            //работает, если текст выравнен следующими способами
            //при необходимости можно обработать остальные случаи
            if(align & Qt::AlignLeft) {
                mevent->setLocalPos(QPoint(w/2,h/2));
            } else
            if(align & Qt::AlignRight){
                mevent->setLocalPos(QPoint(rect.width()-w/2, rect.height()/2-h/2));
            } else
            if(align & Qt::AlignHCenter) {
                mevent->setLocalPos(QPoint(rect.width()/2 , rect.height()/2));
            }
        }
        default: break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

в конструкторе `MainWindow`:

```
ui->label->setOpenExternalLinks(true);
ui->label->installEventFilter(this);
```